# How do I loop through the rows of an Access report?

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

My report looks something like this:

```
PK | Address

1  | address details

2  | address details
```

etc.

On the report, I want to replace PK with the person's name from a different table, e.g.:

```
PK     | Address

John   | address detail   <-- if PK = 1 then display "John"

Howard | address detail <--- if PK = 2 then display "Howard"
```

etc.

How would I go about this?

Comment: It rather depends what your 'something something' is. If it is you want to display something on the report based on other values then yes you can do this, if it is that you want o perform some other, non-report related action would you not be better pulling the recordset from the report and cycling through this? We need more detail on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have two tables in your DB, tbl_Clients where you have the names of clients like,

```
clientID    |   clientName
------------+--------------
1           |   John
2           |   Howard
```

and the other is tbl_Address like,

```
addressID   |   clientID_FK     |   Address
------------+-------------------+-------------------
1           |   1               |   123, Crazy Lane
2           |   2               |   456, Awesome Lane
```

Now if your report's recordsource is based on the table tbl_Address, you can simply change it as a Query. Like

```
SELECT tbl_Clients.clientName, tbl_Address.Address 
FROM tbl_Address INNER JOIN tbl_Clients
ON tbl_Address.clientID_FK = tbl_Clients.clientID;
```

Once this is done, you will be seeing the client name instead of the client number. Hope this helps !